# Sending int from java to c

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, int

I'm trying to send 5 ints from a java server to a c client.

Here is my java code :

```
class Server {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

 while(true)
 {
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

    System.out.println("welcomeSocket.accept() called");
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

    outToClient.writeInt(1);
    outToClient.writeInt(2);
    outToClient.writeInt(3);
    outToClient.writeInt(4);
    outToClient.writeInt(5);
    outToClient.close();
    connectionSocket.close();
 }
  }
}
```

Here is my c code :

```
// the function below is made by made, it creates and return a socket
// AF_INET witch a tcp protocol
int sock = socketClient("localhost",8080);
if (sock < 0) { 
    printf("client : erreur socketClient\n");
    exit(2);
}

char intBufferCoupReq[20];

int data = recv(sock, intBufferCoupReq, 80, 0);
printf("data recieved : %d\n",data);
if( data == -1){
    printf("Error while receiving Integer\n");
}

char intBufferCoupReq2[5][4];

int cpt;
int j;
int i = j = 0;

// in this loop I divide my big array of 5 ints into 5 differents
// array to use with ntohl
for(cpt = 0; cpt < 20 ; cpt++){
    if(cpt%5==0) i=0;
    if(j%4==0) j=0;

    intBufferCoupReq2[i][j] = intBufferCoupReq[cpt];
    i++;
    j++;


}

int receivedInt[5];
for(cpt=0;cpt<5;cpt++){
    printf("int n°%d = %d\n",cpt+1,ntohl(*((int *) &intBufferCoupReq2[cpt])));  
}


close(sock);
```

The first time the c client make a request it is kinda fine :

```
data recieved : 20
int n°1 = 4
int n°2 = 3
int n°3 = 2
int n°4 = 1
int n°5 = 5
```

But the second time ( without shutting the server down ) I get this :

```
data recieved : 8
int n°1 = 16384
int n°2 = -1610612736
int n°3 = 11010050
int n°4 = -1342118655
int n°5 = 524519
```

And my java server crash with a " connection reset " error.
The two program run in localhost on the same computer, port 8080.

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days but i am really clueless.
Do any of you guys got a piece of advice ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C program, please replace:

```
char intBufferCoupReq[20];

int data = recv(sock, intBufferCoupReq, 80, 0);
printf("data recieved : %d\n",data);
if( data == -1){
    printf("Error while receiving Integer\n");
}
```

With:

```
char intBufferCoupReq[1024];
memset(intBufferCoupReq, '\0', sizeof(intBufferCoupReq));

int k = 0;
while ( 1 ) { 
    int nbytes = recv(sockfd, &intBufferCoupReq[k], 1, 0); 
    if ( nbytes == -1 ) { printf("recv error\n"); break; }
    if ( nbytes ==  0 ) { printf("recv done\n"); break; }
    k++;
}
```

This is done to make sure that all packets sent by server are received properly.

Update: added code to confirm data received below. Java program send the integers in network-byte-order, this need to be converted to host-byte-order.

```
int *myints = (int*) intBufferCoupReq;
int i = 0;
for ( i=0; i<(k/4); i++ ) {
    printf("myints[%d]=%d\n", i, ntohl(myints[i]));
}
```

Comment: It's working great thanks.
Helped me a lot.
I just have a few questions :

You set the array "intBufferCoupReq" size to be 1024 bits.
It is way to big isn't it ?
Is it to make sure that the array is long enough ?

And why do i receive the integer in that order ? ( 4 3 2 1 5 ) when my server send it in that order ( 1 2 3 4 5 ) ?

Thanks again !

Comment: Yes, it is better to have big buffer. 1024 byte (not bits) is not too big. This is as precaution in case your server misbehave and send more than the buffer size.  In TCP, the order received must be same as order sent. Please check again.

Comment: Please see my edit which contains extra code to confirm the data received.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing as what i already did in my code, at the very end of my c code ? :_
int receivedInt[5];
for(cpt=0;cpt<5;cpt++){
    printf("int n°%d = %d\n",cpt+1,ntohl(*((int *) &intBufferCoupReq2[cpt])));  
}_

Comment: I see. The assigment logic is incorrect. For each loop, `i` is changed from 0 to 4, while at the same time `j` also changed from 0 to 3 then 0, ... etc. This means it is assigned 'somewhat diagonally'. Try print value `i` and `j` inside the loop to see this.